# mysql split field and concat sorted result

Tags: mysql, sorting, split, concatenation

I have a field in my database containing X number of entries. I would like to split this entries, sort them alphabetical and concat them again.

```
CREATE TABLE `crates`(`crate` int(2), `fruit` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY `crate`);

INSERT INTO crates VALUES(1,'apples');
INSERT INTO crates VALUES(2,'lemons,apples');
INSERT INTO crates VALUES(3,'lemons,bananas,apples');
```

So I've got:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM crates;
+-------+-----------------------+
| crate | fruit                 |
+-------+-----------------------+
|     1 | apples                | 
|     2 | lemons,apples         | 
|     3 | lemons,bananas,apples | 
+-------+-----------------------+
```

I want this to be my result:

```
+-------+-----------------------+
| crate | fruit                 |
+-------+-----------------------+
|     1 | apples                | 
|     2 | apples,lemons         | 
|     3 | apples,bananas,lemons | 
+-------+-----------------------+
```

Where the number of items in the field `fruit` is unknown.

Comment: Storing values as csv  is very bad db design

Comment: legacy i am afraid. :)

Comment: Doing this in pure SQL (especially in MySQL's limited dialect of SQL) may be possible. But it is certain to be an enormous pain in the neck.  You might be wise to consider using Java, php, or some other host language for this.